# Is it possible to get all messages from a queue via JMS without deleting them from the queue?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I would like to know if it is possible to get the messages from a queue through JMS without removing them. There is a `browse()` method in JMX, but is there a similar method in JMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`QueueBrowser`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/messaging/3.0/apidocs/jakarta/jms/queuebrowser). You can create the browser using [`Session.createBrowser(Queue)`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/messaging/3.0/apidocs/jakarta/jms/session#createBrowser-jakarta.jms.Queue-). As the [API doc](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/messaging/3.0/apidocs/jakarta/jms/queuebrowser) states:

> A client uses a `QueueBrowser` object to look at messages on a queue without removing them.
>
> The `getEnumeration` method returns a `java.util.Enumeration` that is used to scan the queue's messages. It may be an enumeration of the entire content of a queue, or it may contain only the messages matching a message selector.

The `Enumeration` contains instances of the `javax.jms.Message` objects from the queue. Therefore you can inspect all the message's headers, properties, and body.